# Invoke web request based on system information

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript

Ok so What I would like is a script that uses the invoke web request command based on a given system info.
So let's say i have two different installers one for a Nvidia gpu system and another for an AMD gpu system, I can already get the gpu info using another script, and save it to a html link or a text file, but how can I use this information, using invoke web request, to download the right installer?

This is the VB script I use to fetch the GPU info:

```vb
strComputer = "."
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer &"\root\CIMV2") 
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _ "SELECT *FROM Win32_VideoController",,48) 
    For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------" 
    Wscript.Echo "Win32_VideoController instance" 
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------" 
    Wscript.Echo"Caption:"&objItem.Caption 
Next
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What have you tried so far? :) And can you perhaps show the existing script to obtain the GPU info? It make it easier to suggest an appropriate way of picking the installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mix-and-match VBS and PowerShell, PowerShell is perfectly capable of querying WMI on its own!

Use `Where-Object` to filter the results based on the `Caption` value, then use an `if` statement to determine whether any of each type was found:

```
$allVideoControllers = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_VideoController

if($allVideoControllers |Where-Object Caption -like '*NVidia*'){
    # Found an nvdia card, download and run the nvidia installer in here
}

if($allVideoControllers |Where-Object Caption -like '*AMD*'){
    # Found an AMD card, download and run the AMD installer in here
}
```

Comment: Thanks man I'll give it a try, but looks like exactly what I was looking for